# How to set frame side using java GUI?

Tags: java

I tried to set frame side, but it didn't exactly. `frame.setSize(400,500)` or `frame.setSize(1000, 1000)` get a same side.

Comment: setSide isn't an actual jframe method

Comment: Are you thinking of setSize?

Comment: If you are calling `pack()` on your frame, remove that call.  `pack()` recomputes the size based on the frame's contents, undoing any size you  had previously set with `setSize()`.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Swing? Something else? Add tag.

Comment: setSize() work after removing pack(). Thanks very much!